# Python's textract cuts lines

Tags: python

I'm using `textract` to get text from documents. I use it like this:

```
lines = textract.process(file).decode('utf-8').splitlines()
```

But if the lines are too long, `textract` cuts them to 80 characters. As I know, `textract` uses `antiword` which has an option `-w width` and if the width is equal to 0, the whole paragraph is printed. Is there such option in `textract`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, one has to edit the file `/usr/local/lib/python<version>/dist-packages/textract/parsers/doc_parser.py` (this is where it is in my system):

```
stdout, stderr = self.run(['antiword', filename])
```

should be changed to

```
stdout, stderr = self.run(['antiword', '-w', '0', filename])
```